# I want to set last three bit to zero,but I don't know where My code wrong?

Tags: java

This is my code , I need to set time last three bit to zero. but my code not work.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
time &= ~0x7;
LogUtil.i("test",String.format("%x %s",~0x7,time));
```

This is log

> fffffff8 1506830400944

What it should be is

> fffffff8 1506830400000!

Comment: Why do you think this output is wrong?

Comment: Setting the last 3 bits to 0 would reduce the time by 0 to 7 milliseconds. Is that really what you want or do you mean the last 3 _digits_, i.e. would you expect `1506830400000`?

Comment: It works fine, if you plan to set last 3 digits to zero you should use: time = time - (time % 1000);

Comment: @Eran I have edit it . The result i need should be 1506830400000

Comment: @Thomas Forgive for My poor English . yes !what I want is 1506830400000

Comment: To reset last three digit, you can do `(time/1000)*1000`.

Comment: @TomaszBawor,@Sanket MaKani . I know i can finish it in those way. but why my code didn't work.

Comment: Your didn't work because _bitwise_ operations like `time &= ~0x7` aren't a good fit to set _digits_ the way you want. The main reason is that bitwise operations are using base 2 while the numbers we humans mostly use are using base 10.

Comment: @Thomas I see. Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number is indeed getting converted. The last 3 digits are really set to `0`. The reason why you don't see them is they are converted at binary level.

The conversion of `1506830400944` to binary is this:

```
10101111011010110000101110011110110110000
                                      ^^^
                             last 3 digits are zero
```

Just print `time` before and after the line `time &= ~0x7;` and you'll see the difference.

---

If you want to set last 3 digits to zero for decimal representation, then you can simply do something like:

```
time=(time/1000)*1000
```